# testing an angular checkbox using in jasmin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, jasmine, karma-runner

My situation is as follows:

**directive**

```
scope: { foo:'=' },
template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo"/>'
```

**parent controller**

```
$scope.foo = false;
```

**jasmine test**

```
var cb = iElement.find('input');

$timeout(function() {  // using $timeout to ensure $digest() isn't the issue.
    cb.prop('checked',!cb.prop('checked'))
},0);

expect(cb.prop('checked')).toBe(true); // passes

expect($scope.foo).toBe(true); // doesn't pass
```

My question: why doesn't $scope.foo get updated when I issue the prop('checked') even though the DOM does (as I've verified after inspecting it).

Here is a jsbin that roughly demonstrates the problem http://jsbin.com/kapifezi/2/edit

Comment: Asked a different way - what is the correct way to test a checkbox (that lives in a directive) who's ng-model is linked to a variable in its parent controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further investigation - it looks like angular will add a `click` listener when you add an ng-model to something like a checkbox.

So it would seem that the correct method of testing this would be to issue a `click event` on the DOM object from within the jasmine test.

Comment: Actually - I recently ran into an issue (possibly related to using `click` here) where Firefox fails to pickup the click event (or perhaps the change didn't enact a `$digest` loop - regardless of my explicit call to `$digest()` directly after the `click` -- although tests pass in both Chrome and PhantomJS. Not sure what's going on...

Comment: Thanks @Kevin your comments saved my day 
In my test    el.prop('checked', true) did not work but once changed to el.click() the model was correctly updated

Answer (score 9):

So the complete answer would be:
You need to change 'checked' property, and then trigger click event.

```
var input = element.find('input');
input.prop('checked',!input.prop('checked'));
// input.triggerHandler('click');
input.triggerHandler('change');
```

Thanks Kevin, that helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
expect($scope.$parent.foo).toBe(true);
```

updating answer:

```
$timeout(function() {  // using $timeout to ensure $digest() isn't the issue.
      //cb.prop('checked',!cb.prop('checked'));  
      $scope.val = !cb.prop('checked');

},0);
```

you want to keep all updates on the scope level and let angular manage the cycles by itself. if updated the property you're off angular's radar.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $scope.$parent. In any case, foo does not exist there. If I understand correctly, in order to access the isolated scope created by the directive, I need to use the scope that is returned by, for example:


`ele = angular.element('<directive></directive>');`
`$compile(ele)($rootScope)`
`isolated_scope = ele.scope();`

Comment: sorry about the typo. fixed the answer. the new input in the template has its own scope. you pass the value, but should be able to access the parent value.

Comment: Maybe my question is unclear - in this jsbin example: [link](http://jsbin.com/kapifezi/5/edit) why doesn't my scope variable `$scope.val` get updated?

Comment: if i got it right, you want by clicking the button to update both checkbox and labels. to do that, replace the line 'cb.prop('checked',!cb.prop('checked'));' with 
'$scope.val = !cb.prop('checked');' - works on my end.

Comment: Ya you're right - that does work - but not in the way that I need/want it to. If you notice, $scope.val is tied to the ng-model of the checkbox directive, so in my mind, it would make sense that if the checkbox were to change from checked to unchecked, ng-model should pick up on this change. Or maybe my understanding of how MVC is interacting is skewed. In either case, I suppose I can do something as you suggested above for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@egoproxy answer helped me in the end, but I had issues with using a raw dom element. To get around this I used `angular.element(domElement)` which: *wraps a raw DOM element or HTML string as a jQuery element.*

```js
var checkbox = angular.element(checkboxElement));

// Click to check it, then Change to propate to ngModel 
checkbox.trigger('click');
checkbox.trigger('change');
```