# Simulate Input Radio Button Selection In Uni Test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Unable to simulate click action on radio button in unit test.

This is the 'it' block :

```
var element = '<div> <my-directive></my-directive></div>';
element = $compile(element)($rootScope);
$rootScope.$digest();

var radio1Button  = element.find('input')[1];
var radio2Button  = element.find('input')[2];

angular.element(radio2Button).trigger('click');
expect(radioModel).toBe('radio2Button');
```

This test is failing , expected is radio2button should get clicked and the ng-model value will change from radio1Button to radio2Button.

Answer (score 1):

Use `triggerHandler` instead

```
angular.element(radio2Button).triggerHandler('click');
```

Consider the similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774995/testing-an-angular-checkbox-using-in-jasmin)